# Can I use full text search in Django with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, django, full-text-search

I want to have a similar function to full text search with Django for SQL Server. Instead of using only "icontains", full text search would make it easier to search in text field (e.g. lemmatisation, indexing, etc.)

I've been looking around but it seems there is only full text search for postgres.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

But as my database is stored in SQL Server, I would need something similar for SQL Server.

Does anyone know if such full text search function is available in Django for SQL server or anything else I should try (e.g., Elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has full text search functionality as an optional component, the first Google result for "SQL Server full text search" is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017). Once setup in SQL Server you can use it from any client.

Comment: That is not correct. When using a framework like Django where you are not writing native queries, there needs to be implemented support for the database you are using. The example  linked to in the question uses SearchVector from django.contrib.postgres.search which will not work with a MS SQL database as it was written for a PostgreSQL database